# Chat feed overlay allows question title to cover the "dismiss" link

Tags: bug, chat, design, feed

The "new feed items" chat overlay feature doesn't play very nicely with very long question titles, as they can overlay the "dismiss" action link. This makes dismissing the message harder than it needs to be.

For example, this showed up in the Worldbuilding general chat room just recently:

[image: Screenshot of the "New feed items" chat popup with an overly long question title covering the "dismiss" action link]

Can we perhaps limit the width of the displayed question title so that it never risks overlapping the "dismiss" link? Summarily cutting off the title, or word wrapping it at just to the left of the feed icon, would probably work about equally well in this case.

(For comparison, the full title of the question is *Postapocalyptic, Venus-like Planet Atmosphere, How Long Will It Last, Can It Become Desert-Like Eventually?*.)